# Error using funtion in a new function

Tags: javascript

When I'm trying use function like sleep(2) in a new function I wrote, it's not working.

```
function deleterow(id){
    $.post( "taskpost.php", { "deleteid": id, "delete":true } );
    sleep(1);
    $('#taskslist').load('taskslist.php').fadeIn('slow');
};
```

Comment: Where is `sleep` defined? You're probably wanting to use `setTimeout`

Comment: What does not work? Why do you use `sleep` as opposed to `setTimeout`? What errors are shown if you talk about errors? What’s the expected behavior?

Comment: *"it's not working"* What is "it"? How should "it" work? What happens instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you coded `sleep` function or are you using it from some other library?

If you want to wait for the `post` request to complete try using this:

```
$.post("taskpost.php", { "deleteid": id, "delete":true } )
.done(function(data){
        $('#taskslist').load('taskslist.php').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

If you still want to delay it somewhat you can use `setTimeout` inside `done` callback.

Comment: I guess all solution could work for me, but I choone only yours and it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function as `sleep()` in Javascript. If you are attempting to add a delay to your function, use `setTimeout(callback,delay)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what the problem is. Maybe the `post` in jQuery isn't working. Sometimes when you have a function that can't be found/finished, it stops the previous function from continuing. The other problem is that there is no sleep function. If you are trying to delay, use the [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function.

Good luck!

Comment: `setInterval` is not a good candidate. It executes callback repeatedly after set time. `setTimeout` should be used to execute the function once after timeout.